# Restrict current user from receiving email using wp_mail

Tags: wp-mail

I have created a code through which the current user can add other users to his project. These users are only shown on the project page. They will not have any right to modify the project.

Once these users are inserted to database it sends an email to them. I want to restrict sending mail to the current user. How can I do that?

```
$member_details->user_email = array_map( 'sanitize_text_field', $_POST['user_email'] );
$member_details->user_role = array_map( 'sanitize_text_field', $_POST['user_role'] );
$member_details->status = array_map( 'sanitize_text_field', $_POST['status'] );

$member_details_encode = wp_json_encode( $member_details );

  global $wpdb;

  $member_result = $wpdb->insert( 'wpxa_project_members',

         array( 

              'project_id'     => $_SESSION['project_id'],
              'author_id'      => $post_author,
              'member_details' => $member_details_encode

              ),

         array( 

              '%d',
              '%d',
              '%s'

      )

    );

$user_email = $member_details->user_email;
$subject = "Congrats! You are added to the Project  -  " . "'" . $project_title . "'";
$message = 'If you are not the member of project plz contact us to remove at info@gmail.com';
wp_mail( $user_email, $subject, $message );
```

Comment: it's not clear to me what you want to achieve compared to what happens now ( if something happens right now..) can you clarify?

Comment: @AndreaSomovigo.. I have created an add / remove fields in which I collect emails & other details of per-registered users. The data collected is inserted into database after inserting I email all these members. The first email will be always current user hence I don't want current user to get email. How to restrict current user from receiving mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. Here it is:

```
if ( ! empty( $member_result ) ) {

$user_emails = $member_details->user_email;

for ($i=1; $i < count($user_emails); $i++) { 
    $user_email[] = $user_emails[$i];
}

$to = $user_email;
$subject = "Congrats! You are added to the Project  -  " . "'" . $project_title . "'";
$message = 'If you are not the member of project plz contact us to remove at mineshrai@gmail.com';

wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//after $wpdb->insert function

$current_user =  wp_get_current_user();
$current_mail = $current_user->user_email;
//$user_email = $member_details->user_email;
if($current_mail !== $_POST['user_email'] ){ // send mail only if different from the current_user email
  $subject = "Congrats! You are added to the Project  -  " . "'" . 
  $project_title . "'";
  $message = 'If you are not the member of project plz contact us to remove at info@gmail.com';
  wp_mail( $user_email, $subject, $message );
}
```

Comment: No its not working as `$member_details->user_email;` has more than 1 email. I think it will require `foreach`. But not getting how to do.

Comment: I've edited my answer: use     if($current_mail !== $_POST['user_email'] )

Comment: `$member_details->user_email;` is an array that contains more than one email. How can we use this `$current_mail !== $_POST['user_email']`

Comment: so $_POST['user_email'] is an array? and you're inserting multiple email values in the details of a single user? 
you should array_diff($member_details->user_email,

Comment: sorry the comment above was sent by mistake:

`$user_email = $member_details->user_email; //array as stated
$arr_current=array($current_mail) // create array with the current user_email;
$to_send=array_diff($user_email, $arr_current); //exclude the current user email comparing arrays
wp_mail( $to_send, $subject, $message ); `